# How to output players normally in the connect four game

Tags: java

This is my board class

```
public class Board {
 char[][] grid;
 int width;
 int height;
 int count;
 char player;


public Board(int height, int width){

    count = 0;
    grid = new char[height][width];
    this.width = width;
    this.height = height;
    for(int i = 0; i < height; i++) {
        for(int j = 0; j < width; j++){
            if(i == 0 && j == 0){
                
                grid[i][j] = '┌';
            }
            else if(j % 2 == 1) {
                grid[i][j] = '─';
            }
            else if (i == 0 && j == width - 1){
                grid[i][j] = '┐';
            }
            else if (i == height-1 && j == 0){
            
                grid[i][j] = '└';
            }
            else if (i == height - 1 && j == width - 1){
                grid[i][j] = '┘';
            }
            else if (i == 0){
                grid[i][j] = '┬';
            }
            else if (j == 0){
        
                grid[i][j] = '├';
            }
            else if (i == height - 1){
                grid[i][j] = '┴';
            }
            else if (j == width - 1){
                grid[i][j] = '┤';
            }
            else  
                grid[i][j] = '┼';
        }
    }
}

public void print(){
    for(int i=0; i<height; i++){
        for(int j=0; j<width; j++)
            System.out.print(grid[i][j]);
            System.out.println();
    }
}
```

Below is the put function of the board class. The problem is the put function. You must enter a line from the selectline function and have the player appear on the desired line.
However, no matter how hard I modify the conditional statement, it only appears in the first line.
How do I modify the conditional statement of the put function?

```
public void put(SelectLine setLine) {

    int y=setLine.getY();
    int x = grid.length-1;
    if(count%2 == 0) {
        player = '●';   
    }
    else {
        player = '○';
    }
    
            
        for(int i = grid.length-1; i >=0; i--) {
                if(grid[i][(y-1)*2] != player) {
                    grid[i][(y-1)*2] = player;
                    count++;
                    break;
                }
            }
        

    System.out.println("────────" + player + "'s Turn ────────");
    this.print();       
    }
}


public class SelectLine {
int line;
public void input(){
    
    System.out.print("Select Line : ");
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    line = sc.nextInt();

}
public int getY(){
    return line;

}
```

}
The goal is to keep stacking up like the picture below.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pth6m.png)

Answer (score -1):

Modify your SelectLine class as follows:

```
class SelectLine {
int line;
public int input(){
    
    System.out.print("Select Line : ");
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    line = sc.nextInt();
    return line;
}
public int getY(){
    return input();

}
```

Working code:
https://onlinegdb.com/ryhum-Eu_

You need to take into account that a user may input negative values or such exceeding grid size, though.

Regards.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main
{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Board b = new Board(10, 10);
        b.print();
        b.put(new SelectLine());
        System.out.println("Hello World");
    }
}

class Board {
 char[][] grid;
 int width;
 int height;
 int count;
 char player;


public Board(int height, int width){

    count = 0;
    grid = new char[height][width];
    this.width = width;
    this.height = height;
    for(int i = 0; i < height; i++) {
        for(int j = 0; j < width; j++){
            if(i == 0 && j == 0){
                
                grid[i][j] = '┌';
            }
            else if(j % 2 == 1) {
                grid[i][j] = '─';
            }
            else if (i == 0 && j == width - 1){
                grid[i][j] = '┐';
            }
            else if (i == height-1 && j == 0){
            
                grid[i][j] = '└';
            }
            else if (i == height - 1 && j == width - 1){
                grid[i][j] = '┘';
            }
            else if (i == 0){
                grid[i][j] = '┬';
            }
            else if (j == 0){
        
                grid[i][j] = '├';
            }
            else if (i == height - 1){
                grid[i][j] = '┴';
            }
            else if (j == width - 1){
                grid[i][j] = '┤';
            }
            else  
                grid[i][j] = '┼';
        }
    }
}

public void print(){
    for(int i=0; i<height; i++){
        for(int j=0; j<width; j++)
            System.out.print(grid[i][j]);
            System.out.println();
    }
}


public void put(SelectLine setLine) {

    int y=setLine.getY();
    int x = grid.length-1;
    if(count%2 == 0) {
        player = '●';   
    }
    else {
        player = '○';
    }
    
            
        for(int i = grid.length-1; i >=0; i--) {
                if(grid[i][(y-1)*2] != player) {
                    grid[i][(y-1)*2] = player;
                    count++;
                    break;
                }
            }
        

    System.out.println("────────" + player + "'s Turn ────────");
    this.print();       
    }
}


class SelectLine {
int line;
public int input(){
    
    System.out.print("Select Line : ");
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    line = sc.nextInt();
    return line;
}
public int getY(){
    return input();

}

}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but the problem has not been solved...

Comment: Please see the photo added to the text.

Comment: We usually don't do people's homework for them, nor contribute quite so much code. Instead, we try to encourage people to focus on the real problem and learn how to solve problems. Feeding people doesn't help them. Teaching them to grow their own food does.

Comment: @SoftwareEngineer Do you mean that Kevin won't get help in this question?

Comment: Thank you all for your interest in my question.

Comment: After a long thought, I corrected the conditional statement and solved it!

Comment: I mean that a) Kevin should provide a minimal example, rather than all good homework (if that's what it is), and b) your solution is in a form that is discouraged her. Code only answers are not really acceptable. We prefer explanations of the solution. We are here to help people learn to solve these problems themselves. And no, I can only downvote once